# How do i pass arguments to a Drupal View?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I need to pass arguments from my module to a View; for example, i want to pass a part of the node title and need to get all the nodes that start with that value.

I cannot use exposed filters because i have a particular layout that am not able to design using exposed filters, so i need to pass arguments programmatically.

I thought to use Contextual filters but i have not found a way to specify the "Starts with" directive.

What can i do to pass filters/arguments ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$view = views_get_view('machine_name_of_view');
$view->set_arguments(array('argument1', 'argument2'));
$view->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$nids = array(123);
$view = views_get_view('news');
$view->set_arguments($nids);
$preview = $view->preview('page_1');
$view->destroy();
return $preview;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $nid_str = implode(",",$nid_arr['nid']); // i.e. "1,2,3,4"

  $view = views_get_view('view_name');
  $view->set_display('view_display');
  $view->set_arguments(array($nid_str));
  $view->dom_id = 'view_dom_id';
  $output .= $view->render();
```

Comment: It is generally better to explain what you have done with your code. Be constructive.